# How do I pad a number in the absence of a minus sign with string.Format()?

Tags: c#

I am overriding the `ToString()` method of a matrix class so I can copy the contents from the watch window into a text editor to perform further analysis.

The idea is that `ToString()` should return something like this:

```
[M11:-1.00 M12: 0.00 M13: 0.00 M14: 0.00]
[M21: 0.00 M22: 0.00 M23:-1.00 M24: 0.00]
[M31: 0.00 M32:-1.00 M33: 0.00 M34: 0.00]
[M41: 0.00 M42: 0.00 M43: 0.00 M44: 1.00]
```

Notice how positive numbers have an extra padding space to compensate for the space the minus sign consumes on negative numbers.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[M11:{0:0.00} M12:{1:0.00} M13:{2:0.00} M14:{3:0.00}]\n[M21:{4:0.00} M22:{5:0.00} M23:{6:0.00} M24:{7:0.00}]\n[M31:{8:0.00} M32:{9:0.00} M33:{10:0.00} M34:{11:0.00}]\n[M41:{12:0.00} M42:{13:0.00} M43:{14:0.00} M44:{15:0.00}]",
            M11, M12, M13, M14, M21, M22, M23, M24, M31, M32, M33, M34, M41, M42, M43, M44);
    }
```

This outputs the following:

```
[M11:-1.00 M12:0.00 M13:0.00 M14:0.00]
[M21:0.00 M22:0.00 M23:-1.00 M24:0.00]
[M31:0.00 M32:-1.00 M33:0.00 M34:0.00]
[M41:0.00 M42:0.00 M43:0.00 M44:1.00]
```

I would like to add padding spaces to positive numbers so they all line up nice, therefore making my debugging tasks easier.

Unfortunately, [there seems to be no placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for the sign in `string.Format()`.

I guess I could use `.ToString()` on each element, use `Pad()` and then assemble them all, but I still think there may be a way to achieve this without having to manually assemble the numbers and creating a lot of garbage in the meantime.

Is it possible to do this inside `ToString()`? or do I need to manually pad each number so the periods align nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a format similar to:

```
    [M11:{0: 0.00;-0.00} M12:{0: 0.00;-0.00}...
```

Look at the section headed [`The ";" Section Separator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator) in the MSDN article you linked.

Comment: This is indeed correct. I have to admit I was looking for something like a "sign placeholder", and therefore skipped the "section separator" part, as its name did not hint it would be helpful to solve my problem at the moment.